# Using bash to transform a numeric sequence

Tags: r, bash, shell

Here is a vector of numbers I have which ascend (it is called `t8_`)

```
2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 91 92 94
```

the problem is that some number happen two times - I don't want to remove them but they have to become two numbers which are unique and not floating point. So I thought about at first iterating through the vector

the next vector would be

```
2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 92 92 94
```

then the same process again

when the vector would be

```
2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 92 93 94
```

For the example this works

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -a vec; do
        # INT_MIN for bash: 32-bit bash also supports 64-bit integers.
        min=$((-1<<63)) 
        for ((i = 0; i < ${#vec[@]}; i++)); do
                (( min = vec[i] = vec[i] > min ? vec[i] : min + 1 ))
        done
        echo "${vec[@]}"
done
###
```

The problem is that it does not for my real vector which looks like that https://www.dropbox.com/s/vp67eiw4ns9rr07/num?dl=0.

When I do `un.sh < vec` I just don't get any output in this specific instance. Could somebody tell me why?

Comment: tr would mean?...I dont really know how I would feed a file to this?

Comment: @shellter It doesn't, your example simply removes duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

I can't say why your shell code isn't working for you, but I can offer you a Perl solution that works fine with your data

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my @numbers = split ' ', do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'num';
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

for my $i ( 1 .. $#numbers ) {
  ++$numbers[$i] if $numbers[$i] == $numbers[$i-1];
}

say "@numbers";
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
tr ' '  '\n' <file | awk '{ if(old >= $1) $1 = old + 1; old = $1 } 1' | tr '\n' ' '
```

This assumes your numbers don't overflow `awk`'s (signed) integers.

The first `tr` changes your sequence from a long line to a column.  The second one changes it back.

Answer (score 2):

Your code *does* work on your real vector. It just doesn't work on your file `num`. The reason is that your file `num` has no line ending, and `read` only processes a line once it gets the line ending. **[Edit: Good point by rici (in the comments): `read` actually does process the line correctly, it just generates a non-zero exit status due to the missing line ending, so the `while` body is not executed for the line.]**

I fixed this on my local machine by copying the file to `num-with-eol`, editing the copy in vim, and running `:set nobin eol` and then `:wq`. I was then able to run your code as a one-liner to produce the desired output, as follows:

```
{ while read -a vec; do min=$((-1<<63)); for ((i = 0; i < ${#vec[@]}; i++)); do (( min = vec[i] = vec[i] > min ? vec[i] : min + 1 )); done; echo "${vec[@]}"; done; } <num-with-eol >|num2;
```

Here's a screenshot of how these three files look in a vim session, with my customizations (and an added red box highlighting the relevant file properties):

[image: vim]

Comment: That's not quite correct. `read` will process the line correctly. However, because the line is not terminated with a newline character, it generates a non-zero status return. ("The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered...") So the `while` statement won't execute the body even though `vec` has been correctly filled in. (That's a standard gotcha with `read` applied to non-standard files.)